# Can anyone help me howto import a module class?

Tags: python

I have a module example.py with the follow class:

```
class add:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x= x
        self.y= y
    def adding_two_nbr(self):
        return self.x*self.y
```

when I import the module as the following i got error:

```
import example 
obj = example.add(1,2)
obj.adding_two_nbr()
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'add' object has no attribute 'adding_two_nbr'
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce your error. seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Have you actually saved the example.py file recently?  Perhaps you're importing a version on disk that's from before you added the `adding_two_nbr` method.

Comment: On which file you are trying to import the example module?

Comment: Please show `print(dir(obj))`

Comment: Run your first two lines in the console, then type sorted(dir(obj)) and make sure you see adding_two_nbr in the resulting list.

Comment: maybe that's because you call the method `adding_two_nbr` while you multiply them. LOL

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me smoothly. Change the second block of code as

```
import example 
obj = example.add(1,2)
print(obj.adding_two_nbr())
```

Save this file as import_file.py in the same directory as example.py and run import_file.py.

Comment: it works fine now after saving it to different name and reload it.   not sure why that's the case. thanks.

Comment: Hi, if the answer helped you, can you accept ? It is just to ensure that others who see the question in future are helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think **add class** is already defined in python module so you need to change to another name

```
AttributeError: 'add' object has no attribute 'adding_two_nbr'
```

**adding_two_nbr**  not defined in python add module.